# Query runs fast accorindg to SQL_TRACE yet actual completion time is much longer

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I've got a query, by setting timing on in SQL*PLus and autotrace traceonly, found to take 40 seconds to complete.

Yet from the SQL trace file collected, the query takes around 10 seconds to complete.

```
call     count       cpu    elapsed       disk      query    current        rows
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
Parse        1      0.02       0.02          0          0          0           0
Execute      1      0.00       0.00          0          0          0           0
Fetch    19537      2.66       6.49         77      61929          0      293035
------- ------  -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------  ----------
total    19539      2.68       6.52         77      61929          0      293035
```

Machine running SQL*Plus client and database are geographically located in the same center, and on the same local LAN.

Display already suppressed so rendering should not be an issue. 
The table being accessed, is compressed though.

So where could that 30 seconds goes? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked v$session_wait to see if the wait events of the session give you the answer?

Comment: Is there anything else in the trace file (other queries...)?

Comment: 293035 rows over the network? What is the actual query?

Comment: Did you run the trace straight after the first query, which means that it's likely the results will be partially cached.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys for late response. Was de-routed to work on something else for quite some time. I think I got the answer. Kind of stupid mistake I didn't realize before. It was the fetch size of SQLPlus matters. By setting arraysize as 5000 (default is 15), I got the execution time close to fetch time as the no. of roundtrip between client and server significantly reduced.

And in response to some suggestions/questions from you:
1. Checked v$session_wait? 
Sad that I didn't perform it at first glance. I notice the flaw by looking at SQLPlus stats. Thanks for the advice. I will check this as well next time.
2. Is there anything else in trace file?
There is nothing else in the trace file. Well, I mean there is no other major SQL being executed during the same session.
3. Actual query?
Sorry that I can post it here. But the amount is expected.
4. Run trace straight after query?
No. I cleared cache first. Then enable trace and execute query. So the result is not driven by any cache.

Thanks all again :)